# Delphi 2010 locking and then closing while importing WCF wsdl

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to import a wsdl for a web service developed on WCF 4. It's hosted on AppFabric, and it has a basicHttpEndpoint binding.
When try to import it, Delphi locks up, and bds.exe's memory consumption starts to go up... it goes from 100 MB to 700 MB. After about 15 seconds, Delphi just implodes, closing itself. There is no error message. Why is this happening? How can I see what's wrong?
I've been able to import WCF 4 wsdl from the same server, with the same bindings, and use them, so I'm kinna stuck. 
Tks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the command-line importer. It may show you errors. And there are LOTS of options to play with.

c:\path-to\WSDLImp.exe -Ow+ -Od+ -DC:\path-to-output-dir\ path-to\my.wsdl

Those options (-O with either a + or - to turn on/off) are things that work for me. YMMV.
Also, there's a DelphiXE WSDL importer that you can use.

Comment: Tks, I'll try it. I downloaded Delphi XE trial, and with Update Pack 1, it worked with the WSDL Importer. I'll give it a go with the WSDLImp.exe

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the WSDL is valid by consuming with SoapUI first. If it won't propertly consume (and make reasonable-looking default requests0 with SoapUI, the WSDL is busted and you should return it for store credit.  (tell the other developer that his WSDL won't consume with SoapUI, so you're done until he fixes it).

Comment: +1 I would go for SoapUI before importing it in Delphi, I've had a lot of issues with SOAP services in Delphi lately...